# Hibernate : Update Complex entity throwing NullPointerException without any clue

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Good Day!!

I am developing an application in spring boot which uses hibernate to talk to My-SQL DB.

The problem I am facing here is

I am having a parent entity which is having connections to 4 other child entities. All connections to the child are one to many in the parent entity and the parent entity is the owner of the relationship.

When I do save on parentEntity the data is getting saved from parent to all the childs. But when I try to do the update by passing the parent Entity Id I am getting below error.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.AbstractTypeDescriptor.extractHashCode(AbstractTypeDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.getHashCode(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.getHashCode(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getHashCode(EntityType.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.generateHashCode(EntityKey.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.<init>(EntityKey.java:54)
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "theater")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Theater implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name = "theater_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "theater_name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String theaterName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "theater_type", nullable = false)
    private TheaterType theaterType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id", nullable = false)
    private Location location;

    @Column(name = "no_of_screens", nullable = false)
    private Long noOfScreens;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "theater", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Screen> screens;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "theater", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TheaterScreenScreenTypeSoundType> theaterScreenScreenTypeSoundTypes;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "theater", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TheaterScreenSeatCategory> theaterScreenSeatCategories;


    @Column(name = "theater_status", nullable = true)
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "theater_address", nullable = true)
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "theater_official_site_url", nullable = true)
    private String officialSiteUrl;
    @Column(name = "theater_contact_email", nullable = true)
    private String contactEmail;
    @Column(name = "theater_contact_phone", nullable = true)
    private String contactPhone;
    @Column(name = "theater_gps_link", nullable = true)
    private String gpsLink;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || !(o instanceof Theater))
            return false;

        Theater other = (Theater) o;

        if (id == other.getId()) return true;
        if (id == null) return false;

        // equivalence by id
        return id.equals(other.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (id != null) {
            return id.hashCode();
        } else {
            return super.hashCode();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that does the update as well?

Comment: Have you found decision?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your table contains a row where `theater_id` is `null`, which is illegal for primary keys.

Comment: Theater_id was never null,Entities in the below code using composite key as primary key.@IdClass or @EmbeddedId deal with that.The update can happen only when we deal with the below (child) entities seperaltely, not from the parent. Limitation with hibernate when parent class is having child entity, for which composite key is the primary key

Note: Composite Key is again combination of few Entities, not String,Long its a custom object

private List<TheaterScreenScreenTypeSoundType> theaterScreenScreenTypeSoundTypes;

private List<TheaterScreenSeatCategory> theaterScreenSeatCategories;

Comment: I have no idea what you are writing here. The example in your question has no composite id. The NPE you are seeing is because you have a `null` in the `theater_id` column of some row of your table. If you have other questions, please ask a new question.